# Possible to add a page to the Page library using the List service?

Tags: web-services

I've seen a few posts out there that say you need to use the Copy Service to do this.  I have been partially successful using the List service, but I'm wondering if the list service is intended to be used this way?

Partial success = creating a new document in the Pages library, but I can't specify the name.  It just shows up as `{item id}_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Copy.asmx to do so.You can have a look at one of my [blog post](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/how-to-create-item-in-sharepoint2010-document-library-using-sharepoint-web-service/).I use this web service to upload a file with metadata , I am sure you can do the same for the page library.

Comment: What would I pass in for the `byte[] testDoc` if I don't have a document already?  I just want to create a document of the default content type and specify column values.

Comment: I was able to create a file on the destination server, but when I try to open it I get the error: `This page is not using a valid page layout.  To correct the problem, edit page settings and select a valid page layout." `

Comment: I have not tried this before , but things you can try is to create a page using from the UI and get this file using the Copy.GetItem Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.copy.getitem   or try to get the default page layout for the default content type as byte array using the Copy.GetItem Method.